# Custom attributes on ElasticSearch index

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am tracking events (I have an event index for my event class) on elasticsearch and I want to include custom attributes as event metadata.

These custom attributes can be defined by the user, so I do not know at front the model. I only know that it will be a well form Json, and I am storing that json as an string in my event class.

I am using C# and Nest library to work with ES.

Example:

```
{
    "EventName": "myEvent",
    "Data": {
        "someAttr": "some Value",
        "someAttr2": "some Value 2"
     }
}
```

So the problem that I have is how to store this in my elastic search event index?

I want to allow the user to search/filter any event using these custom attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `Data` as a `Dictionary<string. object>` on your POCO and index this as an `object` field type in Elasticsearch, which will be indexed as per your example.

Then, you can use a particular key in the dictionary at search time e.g.

```
public class Document
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
}

var client = new ElasticClient();

client.CreateIndex("my-index", c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Document>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Object<Dictionary<string, object>>(o => o
                    .Name(n => n.Data)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

creates the following mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "data": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then we can search against a specific key

```
client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Term(f => f.Data["sameAttr"], "some Value")
    )
);
```

which would be the following search

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "data.sameAttr": {
        "value": "some Value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One thing that you need to be aware of if allowing arbitrary keys is that the value type must be the same for a given key in `Data` in different documents; there are *some combinations of types that may convert in order to index*, but the `_source` will still be what you sent. To avoid any potential issues, use the same types for the same keys.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's really simple.

If "someAttr" and all the other attributes are simple field I think you dont need anything specific in your mapping so you can just index your data.

But if your attributes(inside "Data") are complex objects you should define "Data" as `type : nested` in youe mapping.
you can read about [Nested datatype over here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/nested.html#nested)